# How to organize import in Eclipse but not *change* star imports

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I'd like to configure the organize import in Eclipse with one caveat: I do NOT want Eclipse to CHANGE the imports related to star imports (like import javax.xml.parsers.*).

I would like Eclipse not to expand (replace the star import with each specific ones) if there is already a star import, but also not automatically add the star when there is not.

In fact, I would like the organize import to just organize the imports (ie reorder), not *change* them. Any idea ?

I like it when IDE do not mess with developer's will.

Comment: I don't think that's supported.

Comment: I would not call it "organizing" when wildcard imports aren't resolved :-)

Comment: import statements ending with an asterisk are poor coding practice.  Declare your class’s dependencies explicitly.  If there are so many that it seems ungainly, you probably need to split up the functionality of your class into multiple smaller classes.  You definitely should not be putting effort into preserving asterisk imports.

Comment: @Dwb "using * in imports is the sign of an inferior (lazy) developer" => that is kinda a harsh statement. There are case (not many in my opinion but still) where it makes sense to use stars. And it's up to the dev to chose. Devs must be in control to write the most expressive code each time. And by the way, I would say that being lazy makes great devs to do the task at hand in a minimum amount of time. And being lazy on the long term is good cause you'll write good code requirering low maintenance cost. I am lazy (in the good sense) and felt insulted by this comment.

Comment: @VGR In case of junit tests, I rather have my mockito import as a single star import than having 30 ... but for the rest of my code, I don't want start import, only for tests.

Answer (score 6):

The ***Organize Imports* command can only be executed as a whole**
(see [source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/core%20extension/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/OrganizeImportsOperation.java)) and the *Sort Members* command ignores import statements.

As **workaround to reorder/sort the import statements alphabetical** use the [AnyEdit Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) plug-in:

1. **Select the lines** of import statements to reorder/sort
2. **Right-click** selection and choose ***Sort > Case-Insensitive A-Z***

**For `.*` import statements only**, set the number of imports needed for `.*` to 0 (see [Eclipse help - *Organize Imports Preferences*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-organize-imports.htm)):

1. Open ***Window > Preferences: Java > Organize Imports***
2. Set ***Number of imports needed for .* (e.g. 'org.eclipse.*')*** to **0** (instead of 99)
3. Click ***Apply and Save***

**For adding import statements manually or via content assist only**, disable *Organize Imports* on save (see [Eclipse help - *Clean Up Preferences*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-cleanup.htm)):

1. Open ***Window > Preferences: Java > Code Style > Clean Up*** (or for project specific settings: right-click project, choose *Properties: Code Style > Clean Up*)
2. Click ***Edit...***
3. In the ***Code Organize*** tab uncheck the ***Organize imports*** checkbox
4. In the ***Unnecessary Code*** tab uncheck the ***Remove unused imports*** checkbox
5. Click ***OK*** and ***Apply and Save*** to close both dialogs

Comment: Sorrybut it does not work. In Eclipse Oxygen (from 2017/09) at least. Setting to 0 is the same as "1": all imports are changed to use the wildcard import but it is not what I want (ie "no Eclipse, please don't modify what the developer wrote apart from reordering")

Comment: The _Organize Imports_ command can only be executed as a whole. But if you have no blank lines to group import statements, you could use AnyEdit's text sort function (see my extended answer above).